# "Undo" Button in VBA that restores an entire version of a Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros, worksheet-function

I currently have a macro-enabled spreadsheet that performs various functions including updating, creating, and removing hundreds of rows. If, for whatever reason, one of these functions goes haywire and deletes information that was meant to keep - I would like to implement an "Undo" button that restores the version of that spreadsheet that was just altered by the macro.

I assume it will look like the following:

```
    Public InstanceOfWorksheet As Range

Sub Button_Click()
    InstanceOfWorksheet = CurrentWorksheet.UsedRange 'Or something like this
    'Macro functionality here
    CurrentWorksheet.Update() 'Worksheet has now been updated
    End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
    InstanceOfWorksheet = CurrentWorksheet.UsedRange 'Or something like this
    'Second Macro functionality here
    CurrentWorksheet.Update() 'Worksheet has now been updated
    End Sub

Sub UndoLastMacro_Click()
    CurrentWorksheet = InstanceOfWorksheet
    End Sub
```

So in this case, when you activated the UndoLastMacro command, you would effectively "restore" the version of the Worksheet you had prior to the last Macro called.

My question is, what variable type should `InstanceOfWorksheet` be, and what would be the easiest way to copy the contents of `InstanceOfWorksheet`back into the current Worksheet?

Thanks in advance! : )

Comment: You need more than one variable for this, a range variable and an array variable with the data type `Variant` to hold the values of the target range. This assumes your changes only pertain values. If formulas, formatting etc. is also changed, it's much more complicated.

Comment: On second thought, an easier and safer approach would be to make a temporary copy of the worksheet which gets deleted if no errors occur while the changes are made. Use `On error resume next` and delete the temporary copy if `Err.Number = 0` at the end.

Comment: You may be better off create a new worksheet to store `.UsedRange.Formula`. It is hard for VBA to undo unless every change is  logged. Alternatively, just Save a copy of the workbook to Temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this in the code

```
Sub Button_Click()
    Dim TemporaryFileName as String
    TemporaryFileName = "FileName" 'You can include a path here too like "C:\Wherever\FileName"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs(TemporaryFileName)
    ... (code to be run
End Sub

Sub Restore_Button_Click()
    Workbooks.Open(TemporaryFileName)
    ThisWorkbook.Close False ' Won't save. Maybe set to true if you don't want to lose it just yet

 End Sub
```

You will also probably need to add a button to save it as whatever the file was originally called so that the "new" backup workbook replaces the one that was corrupted by your macro.

Hope this helps

Comment: SaveAs changes the workbook to the new name.  SaveCopyAs would be better because it saves a copy without changing the workbooks name.